# Scrape multiple of the same element

Tags: php

Currently I am scraping a website using [**simple_html_dom.php**](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/) and it's working nicely, how ever I stumbled upon a problem. [**View my demo here**](http://news.wubstub.com/t/test.php).

I currently have this line of code.

```
$article = $html2->find('div.top-content > article > p',0);
print $news['article'] = $article->plaintext;
```

Which should be pulling all of the `p` elements, if I am not mistaken but it's only pulling the first `p` element on the website I am scraping.

[image]

So I am wondering how I would be able to pull all of the `p` elements from this website. [**Website here**](http://screenrant.com/star-wars-force-awakens-concept-art-rey/).

Comment: @FirstOne I'm not completely sure honestly, from reading documentations it says to include it when scraping though unless it's direct `html` that you're scraping. - Just removed it, and it made it so the description doesn't show at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [manual](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual_api.htm):

> Returns the Nth element object if index is set, otherwise, return an array of object.

So when you specify `,0`, you just get the first element that matches the selector.

You can leave this out, and you'll get an array of objects. Then you need to loop through the array:

```
$articles = $html2->find('div.top-content > article > p');
foreach ($articles as $article) {
    echo "$article->plaintext<p>";
}
```

Comment: Gotta love functions that may return an element or an array of elements depending on the arguments you give it...

Comment: Seems reasonable in this case -- the argument specifically indicates whether you want one or multiple elements.